# How to include an offset component in a linear mixed model in Julia?

Tags: r, julia, mixed-models

I have a linear mixed effects model in R (`lme4`) and I want to run it in Julia using the `MixedModels` package. My problem is that `MixedModels` in Julia does not allow an offset variable as in `lme4`. Any suggestions?

Example: `Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X2|Group + X3|Group + offset(X4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really running a *linear* mixed model (which is, I believe, all that's available in the Julia `MixedModels` at present), then you should just be able to subtract the offset from the response variable, i.e. for linear models (or more generally generalized linear (mixed) models with an identity link), you can just use

```
(Y-X4)~X1+X2+X3+X2|Group+X3|Group)
```

(I don't know whether `MixedModels` is smart enough to evaluate the LHS of the formula for you, or whether you have to precompute `Y2 = Y-X4` and then use `Y2 ~ ...`)

Comment: Your suggestion (subtract offset from dependent variable) is correct for _linear_ models. At first, I tried it with `glmer` in R at a logit link function and I obtained different results between using the offset feature and the subtraction version. After doing the maths on paper, it makes sense that the subtraction works properly only on _linear_ models.

Comment: Yes, and it's why it's important to implement offsets for GLMMs (whereas for LMMs it's just convenience/sugar)